# <Cocoa/Cocoa.h> is Missing

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, xcode4.2

I moved to Xcode 4.0 from Xcode 3.2.x
My existing project was compiling in Xcode 3.2 but when i moved to Xcode 4.0 its giving error in the file ,

ApplicationName_prefix.pch and saying

file not found,

I believe normally this file is suppose to be at

System/Library/Frameworks/Cocoa.framework/Headers

but in my machine this folder "Header" is Missing,

does that mean, Xcode 4.0 was not installed correctly,

PN : some projects compiling properly while some projects giving this kind of issue.

If i need to reinstall, how can i do that

Comment: try cleaning your project... and rebuild

Comment: And if that didn't work, try checking in the Build settings whether the path to your pch is correct.

Comment: Does that mean, <Cocoa.h> was not found in my mac book is expected ?

Answer (score 0):

Check (validate) your project/target build settings and make sure that the right SDK is selected.

Also, check your xcode-select path:

```
term> xcode-select -print-path
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

IIRC for Xcode 3.x this was "/Developer".